# Include filename in JUnit xml file from Karma-JUnit-Reporter

Tags: javascript, junit, jasmine, karma-runner

I need to find a way to include the filename, that a certain test was from, in the JUnit XML results file. It only contains the class name:

```
<testcase name="xxxTest should do Y." time="0.119" classname="Chrome_80_0_3987_(Mac_OS_X_10_12_6).xxxTest">
```

There is a `classNameFormatter` option to pass in when creating the report config in the `karma.conf.js` file, but not sure if there is a way to retrieve the file name using that?

```
// karma.conf.js

// the default configuration
junitReporter: {
  outputDir: '', // results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName.xml
  outputFile: undefined, // if included, results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName/$outputFile
  suite: '', // suite will become the package name attribute in xml testsuite element
  useBrowserName: true, // add browser name to report and classes names
  nameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the name attribute in xml testcase element
  classNameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the classname attribute in xml testcase element
  properties: {}, // key value pair of properties to add to the <properties> section of the report
  xmlVersion: null // use '1' if reporting to be per SonarQube 6.2 XML format
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you could do it as follows:

```
classNameFormatter: function(browser, result) {
    return result.suite[0];
},
```

you can log the structure of the input (browser and result) as such to get to know what data you have:

```
console.dir(result);
```

hope it helps!

Comment: If you have nested suites, this will toss away everything but the root suite name. To preserve the nested structure I use `result.suite.join(' - ')` instead of `result.suite[0]`